# nginx: [warn] low address bits

Tags: nginx, ip, deny, warning

So yeah, i got a list of blocked ip-ranges, and some of them gives me an error in gninx when i try to restart nginx.

```
nginx: [warn] low address bits of 79.8.0.0/12 are meaningless in /etc/nginx/includes/blocked-redirect.conf:9635

nginx: [warn] low address bits of 72.4.0.0/12 are meaningless in /etc/nginx/includes/blocked-redirect.conf:9702
```

Someone knows why i get this error, and how to fix it?

These are some ip-ranges i got from the stats.ripe.net api.

Answer (score 1):

You have bits set in the host part.

Take `79.8.0.0/12`, in binary it is:

```
01001111.00001000.00000000.00000000 = address
11111111.11110000.00000000.00000000 = /12 mask
```

The `.8.` is not inside the net mask.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) for more.

Comment: That's not quite the problem - nginx is complaining the boundaries are not correct. The /12 mask with the correct starting address would be acceptable, as 79.8.0.0 falls inside the 79.0.0.0/12 range which is 79.0.0.1 - 79.15.255.254 The same would apply to the other ip.

Comment: @Drifter104 Yes, so 79.0.0.0/12 is acceptable and 79.16.0.0/12 is acceptable because the host part is all zeros. Just a different way of looking at the same problem.